# Where can I find the implementation of JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looking for the implementation of the native Javascript functions like: `Array.prototype.concat()`, `Document.getElementsByClassName()`, etc.

Just curious how they are implemented?

Comment: Mozilla have a nice reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: @Craicerjack That's a great reference for describing how to use them, but it doesn't say how they're implemented. If I understand the OP's question correctly, they're actually looking for the C code written for each browser to act out this functionality (given that Chromium and Gecko are open source, it must be somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to look at the JS engine source code, which may or may not be open source.
Chrome's V8 for example, is open source:
https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse

But keep in mind that's likely going to be c or c++.

As someone else already mentioned, if you want more of an algorithmic description for how something like getElementsByClassName works, try the Mozilla network.